# combobox select query to export from database MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, combobox

I need help to export Data from Database MySql.

I have combobox1 (I import number of stations from MySql from column stations)
I have combobox2 (Start date, I import from column Dat)
I have combobox3 (End Date, I import from column Dat again)

In the button I need help for query. When users select from combobox1 № of stations - 51350 or other and select from combobox2 Start date - 01.01.2016 and select from combobox3 - End date 31.12.2016 how can export other column with results (the name is vkol) I need to export min,max,avarage value from this column vkol.

I have some code but maybe is wrong:

```
 string MyConString3 = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                "DATABASE=hydrodb;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=;";
        MySqlConnection connection3 = new MySqlConnection(MyConString3);
        string command3 = "";
        MySqlDataAdapter da3 = new MySqlDataAdapter(command3, connection3);
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        da3.Fill(dt3);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt3.Rows)
        {
            string rowz = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
            comboBox3.Items.Add(rowz);
        }
        connection3.Close();
```

On this line `string command3 = "";`

I dont know what query to write, becouse from combobox1 I have 300+ numbers of stations. And in combobox2 and combobox3 this station have too much Dates.. and everytime users will selected different numbers of stations and differents dates to see min,max,avg column of vkol (vkol is the name).

Here `foreach (DataRow row in dt3.Rows)
            {
                string rowz = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
                comboBox3.Items.Add(rowz);
            }`

Users need to see in MessageBox min,max,avg values from column vkol.

Any help, please ?

Comment: Your code snippet above doesnt cover what "command3" is, which makes this a little vague.. chances are your code is wrong, but from this is hard to offer advice.  If you want to find min/max/ave of something you could do just that.. but by the looks of it, you havent tried yet

Answer (score 0):

The following queries c# with mysql which depend on your question can help you.

```
       string command3 = "SELECT min,max,avg from dbname   where stations='"+convert.Toint32(comboBox1.selectedItem)+"' AND WHERE  WHERE startdate='"+comBox2.Value.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD")+"' AND WHERE enddate='"+comBox3.Value.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD")+"' ;//assuming the min,max and avg are columns in your database
```

Note your question is not clear and my answer is based on my understanding

Comment: I have 2 errors :
1. CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'
2. CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: My query is:

string command3 = "select year(Dat),month(Dat),min(vkol),avg(Vkol),Max(Vkol) from hyddnev where station='" + Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem) + "' and Dat between '" + comboBox2.ValueMember.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") + "' and '" + comboBox3.ValueMember.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") + "'  group by year(dat),month(Dat)";

Comment: When I replace combobox2.ValueMember.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") with combobox2.Value.To.String("YYYY-MM-DD") I receive this error:
CS1061  C# 'ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: string command3 = "select year(Dat),month(Dat),min(vkol),avg(Vkol),Max(Vkol) from hyddnev where station='" + Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem) + "' and Dat between '" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") + "' and '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") + "' group by year(dat),month(Dat)";

Comment: CS1501  C# No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments